# How to start a process and then pause it immediately?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I would like to know if there is any command or tool that can be used to start a process and then pause it immediately.

I need this function so that I can have time to attach a debugger to it. I have tried visual studio's /debugexe feature, but the behavior of the program seemed changed. So I need to find other way to attach it and debug.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the real problem is you've got a race condition or other concurrency issue, and so simply running it under a debugger causes the problem to hide itself.

Comment: Thank you all for providing useful comments for my problem. 
Because I am developing a plug-in for the program, I can't modify the source code of the host program.
Therefore the solutions provided by sharptooth and nobugz would be more suitable for my problem. I guess that we have to modify the host program in order to use R Samuel Klatchko and Rytmis's solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CreateProcess() with CREATE_SUSPENDED flag. This will start the process with the main thread suspended. Then you call ResumeThread() after having attached.

Answer (score 2):

In your main routine insert the line:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Compile in debug mode.
Run your program and it will break and prompt you to attach a debugger. If you have studio open it will ask if you want to use it to debug.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a [Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx) call as the very first statement.

Comment: That will work most of the times. But if the problem lies in something happening before WinMain() being called it will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a call to

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

in the code. It will suspend the program and then ask you to choose the debugger you want to use. You can then attach to a running Visual Studio instance. If you're already running from a debugger, it will simply break as if it would have hit a breakpoint.